# How to hide columns in excel with no values in a filter list?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large spreadsheet of various chemicals and their specifications; however, not every chemical requires a value in each column so there are a lot of blank cells. I'm wondering if there's something I can do to hide a column if there are no values in it when I select it from a drop-down list filter?

For example, I click on the drop-down list and select "potassium hydroxide" and I want it to hide the columns "Moisture" because there are no values in it.

what it looks like now:

[image]

I tried using some VBA code earlier but I don't seem to get how to incorporate it into the drop-down list filter.

Comment: How many columns do you have? Any chance you have any formulas on your workbook anywhere? This will require VBA

Comment: I have over 100 columns and there aren't any formulas in my workbook anywhere - it's just all user inputted values.

Comment: I'm open to a VBA solution. Right now the last column is CZ but that could change if I need to add new specifications.

Comment: The name of the sheet is "Specifications" and I have three sheets at the moment, with a possible 4, but only the first sheet named "Specifications" is pertinent.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no `Event` for a filter being applied/changed to fire off a macro. However, you can manipulate the `Event`, `Worksheet_Calculate`, to achieve desired result since modifying a filter calculates the sheet. I.E. every time the sheet calculates, the macro is triggered!

---

So now we need to link a filter to a calculation. Any equation will do for this so I am just setting `K1` = `L1` in my example. Ideally, this will be somewhere out of sight (Ideally next to your last used column header to avoid hiding columns not being used)

[image]

---

The macro is making use of the `Aggregate` function by counting the instances of non-empty cells for **visible** rows only. When a filter is applied, any columns that only have 1 visible cell will be hidden. We are using `1` as a base line since all columns will at least have 1 visible cell due to header.

Paste the below code in VBE on sheet `Specifications`. This will not work in a module or workbook template.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Specifications")
Dim LCol As Long: LCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

On Error GoTo SafeExit

Dim HeaderCell As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False

    For Each HeaderCell In ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(1, LCol))
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Aggregate(3, 7, HeaderCell.EntireColumn) = 1 Then
            HeaderCell.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next HeaderCell

SafeExit:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

---

### TLDR

Make sure Sheet has at least 1 equation. When you apply/modify a filter, you force a calculation. When you force a calculation, you trigger the macro. When you trigger the macro, you hide all columns that only have 1 visible cell (which will be the header).

If this runs slow, you can add your range to a `Union` of columns and hide the `Union` (all columns meeting your criteria) once loop is complete.

Comment: I had the sheet formula, and initial solution, to aggregate at first. Guess I should revert it back. Thanks @QHarr

Answer (score 1):

Much in the line of @urdearboy, I'd go as follows

1. place the following formula in any cell in row 1:

   ```
   =SUBTOTAL(3,A:A)
   ```
2. then place the following code in the "Specification" sheet code pane:

   ```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
       Dim col As Range
       With Me.UsedRange
           For Each col In .Offset(, 1).Resize(, .Columns.Count - 1).Columns
               col.EntireColumn.Hidden = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, col) = 1
           Next
       End With
   End Sub
   ```

as you may notice, since the same *chemical* can appear more than one in in column A (e.g.: "Sulfamic Acid"), a column gets hidden only if *all* of its visible cells are empty

Answer (score -1):

try this code:

```
For i = 1 To 500
If Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Columns(i)) = 1 Then
ActiveSheet.Columns(i).Hidden = True
End If
Next
```

Comment: Just a heads up, you should include at least a brief explanation of your answer and how it will help the asker accomplish their goal :)